# CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT is set for postgres but resultset remains open after a commit

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jdbc, db2, commit

I am attempting to use the fact that `connection.commit()` should close all non held resultsets. What should I do to ensure that `connection.commit()` closes all non held result sets?

I have the following source code

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
conn.setHoldability(CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
        ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dummy");

System.out.println("default holdability " + conn.getMetaData().getResultSetHoldability());
//System.out.println("rs holdability " + rs.getHoldability());
conn.commit();
rs.getStatement().isClosed(); //this is false with postgres and mysql
```

As I read the JDBC spec, when a commit is issued on the connection then non held result sets will be closed. I have tried this now with PostgreSQL
, MySQL and DB2. Only DB2 actually closes the resultset. PostgreSQL and MySQL keep the result set open. PostgreSQL is actually really interesting, even when i explicitly close the connection the result set stays flagged as open. I am looking for a reliable way to ensure that after a commit non held result sets are closed. I have attempted to set the default holdibility for the database but this has had no effect, similarly when I use `createStatment` and use `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` this also has no effect in PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Comment: Why are you checking if the statement is closed, if you want to know if the result set is closed? Statements are not closed on close of the result set (unless `closeOnCompletion()` has been called); they remain usable and will automatically enlist a new transaction if necessary. You'd need to query `rs.isClosed()` instead if you want to know if the result set was closed.

Comment: yep as the comment below says, the resultset is also still open. I was testing lots of things and ended up posting sample code that checked the statement but checking the resultset gives the same result. JDBC spec actually says that a commit "can" close a resultset, not that it will. Default JDBC is also to hold cursors over a commit. When i change this flag setting at both the database metadata and on resultset creation postgres continues to ignore it. I tested against DB2 and MySQL and they both behave as expected.

Comment: _"Default JDBC is also to hold cursors over a commit"_, the JDBC specification has no such requirement, specifically it says: _"The default holdability of ResultSet objects is implementation defined." (JDBC 4.2, section 15.1.3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug.

You should open an [issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues) with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: I don't think the question provides sufficient information for the conclusion, especially if what is checked is the statement instead of the result set.

Comment: Yes, but I experimented, and the `java.sql.ResultSet` isn't close either.

Comment: As DB2 and MySQL seem to behave differently to this I would tend to agree it is a "bug" the one thing that holds me back is that a close reading of the JDBC spec is that a "commit <can> close a resultset", emphasis mine. "CAN" is not "WILL".

Comment: In 15.2.5 the spec says: *A `ResultSet` object is implicitly closed when [...] the `ResultSet` is created with a Holdability of 
`CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` and an implicit or explicit commit occurs*. I see no "can" there. I think the "can" you quote means that you have the choice if you want `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` or not.

Comment: Taking the broader view, is it a big problem if the `ResultSet` remains open?